# Should technical stories in Jira be stories or tasks?

Tags: task, jira, scrum, kanban

I am preparing a Kanban board for my team, and under an Epic, you can create three different kinds of issues: Stories, Tasks, and Bugs.

[image]

I discussed with my team whether a Technical story should be a story under Epic or a task under Epic.

Their point being is a story is more on business-related "user story" (not the technical story), and that technical story should fall under Task with subtasks.

As for me, I've gotten used to Scrum boards in different platforms having a technical story as the story, and we create tasks under it.

The subtask of this so-called technical story will contain the following:

- Setup/Configuration
- Investigation
- Check-In/Deployment
- Testing
- Documentation

Whether we create it as a task or a story, I think the process will be the same anyway, but what would you guys recommend we use?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you use it.

Normally,
`A Story:` more detailed functionality

`A Task:` is smaller technical improvements or backend work.

`Recommendation:` Choose based on your team's understanding and workflow. Use retrospectives to adjust your approach based on what works best for your team. The goal is clarity and efficiency in your team's processes.